# Evento after resize do form

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Tenho um projecto em `delphi 2010` no qual estou a tentar criar um evento `after resize`. Existe alguma forma de criar o evento em um form do projecto?

O objectivo seria executar um código só depois de o redimensionamento do `form` estar concluído, e não estar sempre a executar que é o que acontece no `onresize` do `form`.

Comment: Posta o código que esta no resize,

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, o código pode ser um showmessage, se precisares do código mesmo só mais daqui a pouco posso postar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemente nas declarações:

```
procedure WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE;
procedure WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage); message WM_EXITSIZEMOVE;

procedure TForm9.WMEnterSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  {Aqui ele entrou no laço que monitora o redimensionamento, então não Faça nada}
end;

procedure TForm9.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  {Aqui ele terminou de redimensionar}
  ShowMessage('terminou');
end;
```

Detalhe, não implemente o códido e depois execute o atalho para auto declarar os procedimentos, o Delphi ira declarar sem alguns detalhes, tem que ser feito manualmente mesmo!

[No SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645339/how-to-detect-when-form-resizing-starts-and-stops)